# Outlook 2010 calendar view stuck after search

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

After doing a search on calendar items, the default view when switching to calendar remains stuck to the search result list, instead of Day/Week/Month. How can I change this default?

Answer (score 11):

- Open "Calendar > View > Change View > Manage Views..."
- Select view name "Calendar" in the list
- Click "Apply View"

Comment: same issue in newer versions of Outlook with a similar fix: Calendar > View > Change View > Select "Calendar".  Thanks for your answer.